# Class 'App\users' not found in Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel

I am getting the following error:

> FatalErrorException in UserController.php line 23:
>
> Class 'App\Users' not found

Usercontroller.php:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Request;

use App\Users;
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;
use Validator;
use Redirect;
use Session;


class UserController extends Controller
{

   public function index()
   {
      $user=Users::all();
      return view('users.index',compact('user'));
   }


   public function edit($id)
   {
      $user=Users::find($id);
      return view('users.edit',compact('user'));
   }

   public function update($id)
   {
     $userUpdate=Request::all();
     $user=Users::find($id);
     $user->update($userUpdate);
     return redirect('users');
   }

   public function destroy($id)
   {
      Users::find($id)->Delete();
      return redirect('users');

      //Schema::table('books', function ($table) {
      //$table->softDeletes();
//});
   }

}
```

Users.php (its in App/Users.php):

```
    namespace App;

    use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
    use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;


    class User extends Model
    {
        protected $fillable=[
            'name',
            'email',
            'password',
            'remember_token',
            'created_at',
            'updated_at',
            'active',
            'role'
        ];

    }
```

I tried the `composer dumpautoload` and `php artisan config:clear` as well, but it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 5):

`\App\User`, not `\App\Users`. That's all.

Your class name and file name do not match. Either change the class to `Users` or file to `User`.

Comment: The file and class name do match.. the file name is Users.php and the class name is app\Users

Comment: No it is not. `class User extends Model`

Comment: Really didn't see that, it solved the error, I guess this is what happens when 2 people work on one project. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to `use Model`. Add `use App\User;` after `namespace` clause.

Also, rename `Users.php` to `User.php`.

Or you can use this model it like this:

```
App\User::find(1);
```

Comment: It is not saying: 
FatalErrorException in UserController.php line 3:
Namespace declaration statement has to be the very first statement in the script

While it clearly is the first..

Comment: Yes, namespace should be on top of PHP file, but next line should be `use App\User;`. Also, change `Users::` to `User::` in a controller.

Comment: The indent on the namespace was messing it up, I fixed that error, the file is called userS.php so why would I use user?

Comment: Also, rename `Users.php` to `User.php`